# Cruise control.NET tracking the number of times source files are changed?

Tags: .net, scripting

i have configured a ccnet which actually sniffs for the
modifications in my source files present in my local system.My
ccnet.config file will poll every 4 minutes to check for any
modification in the source files.So the problem is like if i modify
the same file twice,when the ccnet polls what i see in the command
window is jst 1 modification is detected instead of 2 modification
which i had done.Can u plz suggest any method by which i can get the
exact number of times my source files gets modified.
to make it more clear:--------
suppose my source folders contain files named a.c,b.c and d.c
If i make modification in a.c and b.c,when my ccnet polls at the exact
interval it shows 2 modifications detected and starts the build
process.Now if i make modification only in a.c for 2 times and when
the ccnet polls it shows only 1 modification detected instead of 2
modifications detected.So can u plz explain this discrepency??

Thanks
Maddy

Answer (score 1):

CruiseControl.Net checks modifications since the last build in order to know whether it should trigger a new build or not. It doesn't need to know how many times a file is modified, only which files have been modified since the last time it checked.

The number of modifications refers to the files that were modified, not the number or times that the file was modified.